# Почему время выполнения одного и того же кода python pygame различается в десятки раз?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Возникла проблема при создании графического приложения на python c использованием pygame. При первых трёх запусках окно с графикой появлялось за доли секунды. На четвёртый запуск время ожидания увеличилось до 10 секунд, а в дальнейшем - до 40! Код - пример использования pygame.draw, скопированный с http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html. Проблема проявляется и в PyCharm, и в IDLE, и при запуске скрипта через консоль. Версия Python 3.9.2, версия pygame 2.0.1

Comment: У меня окно всегда открывается за секунду. Сколько попыток бы я не делал. Win7 + pygame 2.0.0 (SDL 2.0.12, python 3.7.4)

Comment: Пробовал запустить с этими интерпретатором и модулем - всё осталось так же. Лицензионная Win10, с отключенным антивирусом. Не знаю, что и думать.

Comment: попробуйте открыть монитор ресурсов и посмотреть нагрузку, если гдето 100%  то будет яснее, может и не питон виноват.